# Angular mat-form-field add space between label

Tags: angular, datepicker

Hello how can show the mat-label its half hidden.

[image]

Comment: try setting the line height on your css to something greater by maybe 5 to 10 pixels.  you can override the default css using the same names - and you can get them directly from something like chrome dev tools.

Comment: hello and thank you for your reply. line height in wich class?

Answer (score 0):

in the component css file:

```
mat-form-field {
    line-height 55px !important;

}
or
mat-label{
 line-height 55px !important;

}
```

or

```
::ng-deep mat-form-field {
       line-height 55px !important;
}
or
::ng-deep mat-label {
 line-height 55px !important;

}
```

be careful with the later because it is universal.  you may have to play around with the css order of the element.  like I said the best thing to do is to view it with chrome dev tools so you can get the exact class map.

Comment: use exactly what you write I have the same result nothing changed

Comment: the best solution is with z-index to show mat-label front of others because I dont want change the height width of mat-form-field. But no works

Answer (score 0):

my temporary solution is to use
`.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-label-wrapper{ overflow: visible!important; }`

Comment: he asked to make the height larger not change the z-index this is not a correct answer.  otherwise the label will float out of the defined box.

Comment: yeap that I want. the label displayed out of box

Comment: well I guess I owe George an apology

Comment: no worries thanks a lot for your help. the line-height changes the hole mat-form-field height and make it bigger. I just wanted the same size of mat-form-field and only displayed the cut label. So this line works fine but I dont know if is a good aproach.

Comment: if it accomplishes your goal then it should be fine.